# javascript if image does not exist don't load it

Tags: javascript, html, image

I've got a code in javascript that loads an image into a popupwindow. I need to check first if there is an image in the  tags src. If exists, add

```
popupContent += '<tr><td><img src="'+mypath+'"/></td></tr>';
```

else do nothing

```
var mypath = "whatever here but loaded on an ajax get call after hitting a button";
var popupContent = '<table>'; 
popupContent += '<tr><td>Other fields</td></tr>';
popupContent += '<tr><td><img src="'+mypath+'"/></td></tr>';
popupContent += '</table>';
```

Comment: Doesn't your explanation explain what you need to do? What are you struggling with?

Comment: So what is the problem? Explaining what you want is great but where is the issue? I don't see any attempt on your own behalf, all I see is your todo/request list of what you want it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
function checkImageExists(imagePath){

   var httpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
   httpReq.open('HEAD', imagePath, false);
   httpReq.send();

   return httpReq.status != 404;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code and added the check.

```
 var mypath = "whatever here but loaded on an ajax get call after hitting a button";
var popupContent = '<table>'; 
    popupContent += '<tr><td>Other fields</td></tr>';

if (mypath) {
    popupContent += '<tr><td><img src="'+mypath+'"/></td></tr>';
}

    popupContent += '</table>';
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:  If an image is there, it will show the image else will show `No image`.

```
var mypath = "whatever here but loaded on an ajax get call after hitting a button";
var hasImg = mypath ? true : false;
var popupContent = '<table>'; 
popupContent += '<tr><td>Other fields</td></tr>';
hasImg ? popupContent += '<tr><td><img src="'+mypath+'"/></td></tr>' : popupContent += '<tr><td><span>No image</span></td></tr>';
popupContent += '</table>';
```